# Bluetooth socket accept() method doesn't accept connection

Tags: python, sockets, bluetooth, raspberry-pi3

I'm currently trying to connect my Phone with my Raspberry Pi 3 in order to send data from RPI3 to phone.

On raspberry I've written this script :

```
import gobject
import dbus.mainloop.glib
import os
import sys
import time
import bluetooth as bt

dbus.mainloop.glib.DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)

os.system("hciconfig hci0 up")
os.system("hciconfig hci0 piscan")
os.system("hciconfig hci0 iscan")

print "Socket handler ..."
sock_control = bt.BluetoothSocket(bt.L2CAP)
sock_interrupt = bt.BluetoothSocket(bt.L2CAP)

print "Bind ..."
sock_control.bind(("",17))
sock_interrupt.bind(("",19))

print "Listen ..."
sock_control.listen(1)  # Limit of 1 connection
sock_interrupt.listen(1)

print "Waiting for a connection..."
conn_control, conn_info = self.sock_control.accept()
print "Got a connection on the control channel from ", self.conn_info[0]
conn_interrupt, conn_info = self.sock_interrupt.accept()
print "Got a connection on the interrupt channel from " + self.conn_info[0]

while True:
    data = 0x00001e0000000000
    conn_interrupt.send(str(data))
    time.sleep(1)
    data = 0x0000000000000000
    conn_interrupt.send(str(data))
    mainloop = gobject.MainLoop()
    mainloop.run()
```

When I try to connect from my phone to Raspberry, I get nothing and the program is blocked at .accept() waiting for incoming connection even though I'm connected.

This my console print

```
Socket handler ...
Bind ...
Listen ...
Waiting for a connection...
```

I've tried to add `DisablePlugins = pnat` in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` but nothing happened.

Any idea ?